# Flutter get current page to prevent it from re-opening in Navigator.push?

Tags: flutter

I have one AppBar in the entire application. And to go to new pages I use `Navigator.push`. But when I open a new page, for example a "Search", from it I can open new instance "Search" page. How to avoid duplicate pages? Can I determine which page I have open now to prevent it from re-opening?

```
onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Search()),
          );
```

My full AppBar

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return AppBar(
  backgroundColor: getAppBarColor(),
  actions: <Widget>[
    Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Search()),
            );

          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.search,
            size: 26.0,
          ),
        )),
    Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Contacts()),
            );
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.call),
        )),

      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Basket()),
            );

          },
          child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
          )),
     ],
   );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, routeName);
```

if it was defined in the context
or you can use

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, newRoute)
```

if you want to replace the route

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Navigator.push(context, route)`
Use `Navigator.pushReplacement(context, newRoute)`

This'll automatically push a new page replacing the old one, so there won't be any duplication